# AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer error on 3Gs

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I need to show camera output using AVCaptureSession. My code works fine on all devices except iPhone 3Gs:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Receiving events
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didGetError:) name:AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didStartRunning:) name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];

    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    NSString *preset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
    self.session.sessionPreset = preset;
    self.device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    self.input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.device error:nil];
    [self.session addInput:self.input];

    // Setting up the preview layer. It causes the error.
    self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [self.session startRunning];
}


- (void)didStartRunning:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSLog(@"started");
}


- (void)didGetError:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSError *error = notification.userInfo[AVCaptureSessionErrorKey];
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

The output is:
    error: The operation could not be completed
    started

Can you advice me the workaround? Apple's [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) example doesn't work on 3Gs as well.

Comment: it seems that your 3gs doesn't support this operation

Comment: I've tried all the presets and orientations - nothing worked